# Delete multiple files in one command

Tags: command-line

On the Linux command line, I want to delete 3 files in one command, how would I do it?

**For instance, I want to delete:**

```
public_html.tar.gz
dbapp.sql
dbwp.sql
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`rm` takes as many arguments as you pass it. Up to the maximum command line length, usually 32,760 odd characters.

In this case:

```
rm public_html.tar.gz dbapp.sql dbwp.sql
```

To forcibly delete, without confirmation prompts (potentially dangerous!)

```
rm -f FILE1 FILE2 ...
```

See also: [man 1 rm](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rm)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, how would you take off the prompts on whether or not I want to delete?

Comment: @u1sonderzug: Those are not shown by default unless you're removing read-only files, or unless you add the `-i` option. It could be that you have an alias for `rm` to `rm -i`; try `type rm` to check, `unalias rm` to temporarily remove the alias, and look in your shell initialization scripts (the `~/.bashrc` file`) for removing it permanently.

Comment: See update: Use the `--force/-f` option.

Answer (score 2):

Just list them all in a singe line command using `rm -f`. It won't restrict you to a single file entry per delete. The -f options ensures it doesn't prompt you when removing a file.

`rm public_html.tar.gz dbapp.sql dbwp.sql`